# Counting divisors to detect prime number in python 3.7.4

Tags: python

I tried to write a code to detect prime numbers myself and accidentally, I found this which is working just fine:

```
def prime_number_check(inp):
    setp = [ ]
    res = [ ]
    count = 0
    for x in range(1, inp):
        setp.append(x)
    print(setp) #just to control the set
    for y in setp: #set of dividers
        if inp % setp[y-1] == 0:
            res.append(setp[y-1])
        else:
            continue
    print(res) #just to control the set
    for z in res:
        count += 1
    if count > 1:
        print(inp, "is not a prime number!")
    else:
        print(inp, "is a prime number!")
```

I tried to divide the input number, which will be checked whether it is prime or not, to the numbers smaller than itself and wanted to detect the result set whether it has float results or int results, then remove float results with `res.remove()`, then if there is int result other than 1, print `not a prime`, otherwise print `prime`, but I failed; instead found this code which counts divisors.

Could you help me to find out how can I make float/int check in a list and return a result? I tried `bool()`, and `isinstance()` but always got an error about iterability.

Comment: What do you mean by "float divisors"? Every number has an infinitie number of float divisors. The number 3 for example, that is without a doubt considered prime, can be divided by 1.5 and 2, or by 1.2 and 2.5, or by 1.1 and 2.72727272. There is no meaning in finding "float divisors".

Comment: one line code to detect prime number `print(len([i for i in range(1,n+1) if n%i==0])<=2)` if you want to count divisor then remove last condition  `print(len([i for i in range(1,n+1) if n%i==0]))`

Comment: for instance; user entered 8 and my set get the list of numbers from 1 to 7: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], then, with for loop, I divide the input number, which is 8 in this example, by the members of this set, which is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] and I append the results of these divisions into "another set", "result set", which then becomes [8, 4, 2.666 , 2, 1.6, 1.333, 1.142]. then, I want to check this result list, .remove() all float values, only keep integers, and if there is another integer different than the input number itself, the input number is not a prime number, otherwise it is prime number..

Comment: `another = [8, 4, 2.666 , 2, 1.6, 1.333, 1.142]` then `result = [n for n in another if n%1==0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
def prime(*arg):
    if num<2:
      return 0
    else:
      t=0
      for x in range(2,num+1):
         k=0
         for y in range(1,x+1):
           if x%y == 0:
             k += 1
         if k == 2:
           t += 1
      return t
```

Here I actually not considered 0 and 1 as prime . I hope you got my simple code in python.